# How to import appcom v7 library?

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I am using this :
[import appcom v7 library](http://hmkcode.com/add-actionbar-to-android-2-3-x/)

to import appcom V7 library to make my application compatible with older versions.But when i import it then try to finish the setup then i am not able to do so. finish button becomes useless. Where i am wrong ???? any useful help will be appreciated.

Here is the snapshot.[image]

Comment: if you have ADT 22.6 and above then its automatically added as library project when you create new project.... so update ADT

Comment: Please try selecting the option copy projects into workspace. And Yes as Dhawal has mention, update ADT and build tools.